# Issue debugging c strings?

Tags: c, string, gdb

I have some c code to concatenate a string.

```
char str_cat[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1];
```

How do I check the sizeof str_cat in gdb? Right now it reports 0 with:

```
print sizeof(str_cat)
```

<strike>It does print the string, but how do I print it showing the null character?</strike>

Let me reword, how do I verify that str_cat is the proper size and has enough space?

Comment: The terminating NUL is implied. It won't automatically print it. If you want it badly, you can print `theString[strlen(theString)]` as an integer. It shall be `0`.

Comment: It wont show the null character because the null character doesnt look like anything. Is str_cat a function? Shouldn't it be a char * in which case sizeof wont work because it would just return the size of a pointer anyway?

Comment: @Ben `str_cat` is an array of `char`. And if the debugger knows that it's an array, then it will show the size correctly.

Comment: `str_cat` is variable length array. Apparently `gdb` does not know how to deal with VLA.

Comment: Sorry but I don't undertand, you are declaring a char array(code time) with depth based in strlen(run time)?

Comment: @HMarioD: it's the [C99 Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in action :)

Comment: Thanks @pmg is the first time I ear about that, I work with embedded systems VLAs are aliens for me. I need read more. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> char str_cat[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1];
>
> How do I check the sizeof str_cat in gdb? Right now it reports 0 with:

`str_cat` is a variable length array. Apparently `gdb` does not how to deal with variable length arrays.

There is an open ticket here regarding this issue:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9663

it mentions an existing patch but at least my `2012` version `7.4` of `gdb` does not include it.

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the bug in GDB, store the size in a separate variable first, *or* store the size in a separate variable afterwards, e.g.:

```
int len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
char str_cat[len];
```

or

```
char str_cat[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
size_t len = sizeof str_cat;
```

Then print `len` in GDB.